# Circumventing Membership provider using ASP NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I have a very odd question (which might even sound silly..)
I want to integrate 2 different security providers in my new MVC project.
I want to use the new Asp .NET Identity with OWIN for authentication.
And yet I also want to be able to use an existing forum solution (I can't build my own sadly), where most, if not all of them, use either membership provider or simple membership provider.

Is there a way to fool/trick a membership provider into using the new .NET implementation? Is there a way to have them both on a single site?

Another user suggested I create my own membership wrapper around the ASP .NET identity - not sure how that'd work or if it's the only way to go?